# Replace special characters except the following ,.@

Tags: regex, awk, gsub

I'm looking for an option to remove special characters from a file except for the following 3 items ,.@

The following awk command gets close but it removes all punctuation.

```
awk '{gsub(/[[:punct:]]/,"",except(".","@",","))}1' test.csv > test2.csv
```

Any ideas...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no opposite character classes in POSIX and no lookarounds to restrict a more generic pattern with some exceptions. The only way is to spell out the POSIX character class.

According to [*Character Classes and Bracket Expressions*](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html):

> **‘[:punct:]’**
>   Punctuation characters; in the ‘C’ locale and ASCII character encoding, this is `!` `"` `#` `$` `%` `&` `'` `(` `)` `*` `+` `,` `-` `.` `/` `:` `;` `<` `=` `>` `?` `@` `[` `\` `]` `^` `_` `\` `{` `|` `}` `~`.

You may use

```
/[!-+\/:-?[-`{-~-]/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NUQmkS/1).

*Legend*:

[image]

Comment: That's **A** way but it's certainly not the only way and the other common ways of dealing with this are locale-independent.

Answer (score 0):

All 3 of these approaches will work in any locale and will work for any character class by just changing the class name and will work for other bracket expressions or strings etc.:

1) Just look for any punct but only change it if it's not one of the chars you don't want changed:

```
$ echo 'a.b?c#d@e,f' |
awk '{
    new = ""
    while ( match($0,/[[:punct:]]/) ) {
        chr = substr($0,RSTART,1)
        new = new substr($0,1,RSTART-1) (chr ~ /[,.@]/ ? chr : "")
        $0  = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    print new $0
}'
a.bcd@e,f
```

2) Turn the chars you don't want changed into other strings first then turn them back afterwards:

```
$ echo 'a.b?c#d@e,f' |
awk '{
    gsub(/a/,"aA"); gsub(/,/,"aB"); gsub(/\./,"aC"); gsub(/@/,"aD")
    gsub(/[[:punct:]]/,"")
    gsub(/aD/,"@"); gsub(/aC/,"."); gsub(/aB/,","); gsub(/aA/,"a")
    print
}'
a.bcd@e,f
```

Changing `a` into `aA` and back is what guarantees that the strings you create when converting the `@`, etc. are strings that cannot exist elsewhere in the input at that time and that's why you can safely convert them back afterwards.

3) Suffix the puncts with the RS value, then remove the RS suffix from the chars you don't want changed, then change the remaining RS-suffixed puncts:

```
$ echo 'a.b?c#d@e,f' |
awk '{
    gsub(/[[:punct:]]/,"&"RS)
    $0 = gensub("([,.@])"RS,"\\1","g")
    gsub("[[:punct:]]"RS,"")
    print
}'
a.bcd@e,f
```

That one uses GNU awk for gensub(), with other awks you'd need match()+substr().